# what would be regex for below pattern?

Tags: regex, linux, perl

```
<msg info=access_denied>
```

Access_denied can be anything "permit" "Thrashing"

I tried using regex

```
m/<msg info=([^]*)>/i
```

It is giving unmatched regex.

What should be actual and correct regex ?

Comment: Can't you just grep on access_denied?

Comment: What do you mean by "permit" "Thrashing"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your negated character class is missing the `>` character, for anything not `>`:

```
m/<msg info=([^>]*)>/i
```

However, just note that if your data is XML, you should consider using an actual XML Parser to pull that data.

Comment: That is true. Crap !! I feel I might have had Brain freeze. Thanks for your answer. It is not xml data hence I am not using xml parser. 
Thanks ! for suggestion and answer.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for

```
/<msg info=([^>]+)/
```

Assuming the input is as you described (no quotes, etc).

Comment: why + not * ? value could be there or not ?

Comment: I assumed `<msg info=>` would be invalid. Otherwise, yes, use `*`.